# MySQL Family Tree Recursive Query (version 5.6)

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data, family-tree

I am trying to get a query that returns a family tree from the very first ancestor to their last descendant. I am using MySQL version 5.6, and here is the query I came up with:

```
 SELECT   
            p1.individual_id as ParentId,
            p1.first_name as ParentName,
            p2.first_name as Child1_Name,
            p3.first_name as Child2_Name,
            ...
            p10.first_name as Child9_Name,
 FROM individual p1
            LEFT JOIN individual AS p2 ON p2.parent = p1.individual_id
            LEFT JOIN individual AS p3 ON p3.parent = p2.individual_id
            LEFT JOIN individual AS p4 ON p4.parent = p3.individual_id
            ....
            LEFT JOIN individual AS p10 on p10.parent = p9.individual_id
 WHERE 1 IN (p1.parent,
            p2.parent,
            p3.parent,
            ...
            p10.parent)
```

Here is the output I am getting. I am not sure how to change the query so that it returns **just one line** with the very first ancestor and all their children.
[image]

For example, you can see on the screenshot that the parent has different children in `Child2_Name` column ("`Ozubek`" and "`Kaiyr`"), thus we get an additional line for "`Ozubek`" descendants and `Kaiyr` descendants respectively. However, I want them both to be in `Child2_Name` column, not separately. The same is for the rest of the children.

Is it possible to do what I want and group all the children in kind of array? I know I could use the concat, but in that way the children would be a string type separated by commas instead of being an actual object, which makes it difficult for me to use the query results for displaying it in React application...

Comment: MySQL cannot return an actual object as it does not have an object data type. You can concatenate string in a way that it resembles a json object.

Comment: Then it's not possible to use recursion in such a case?

Comment: Recursion is a technique to obtain results. Your question was so far about formatting the output.